# What does -> operator mean in ANTLR3?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlr4

I'm trying to compile a grammar and get it works in ANTLR4. The grammar was written for ANTLR3 and I'm getting a lot of compilation errors. Here is one of them:

```
syntax error: '->' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element
```

This is the rule causing the error

```
tokens {
  ZONE;
  ZONE_OFFSET; 
}

time_zone_abbreviation
  : UTC  -> ZONE["UTC"]
  | EST  -> ZONE["America/New_York"]
  | CST  -> ZONE["America/Chicago"]
  | PST  -> ZONE["America/Los_Angeles"]
  | MST  -> ZONE["America/Denver"]
  | AKST -> ZONE["America/Anchorage"]
  | HAST -> ZONE["Pacific/Honolulu"]
  ;
```

I know the `->` operator can be used to specify lexer command in ANTLR4. But what does the operator mean in ANTLR3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside parser rules, the `->` denotes a rewrite rule in ANTLR 3 that constructs an AST from the parser rule. More about this in this Q&A: [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr)

In ANTLR 4, the `->` is only used in lexer rules to put certain tokens on a different channel (or skip them all together from the token stream). Since [ANTLR 4 does not work with AST's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823333/how-can-i-build-an-ast-using-antlr4), the `->` no longer has an equivalent. When translating an ANTLR v3 grammar to a v4 grammar, simply remove the `->` and everything on the right hand side of it.