# syntax error: 'public' came as a complete surprise to me

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to port working antlr to antlr4 but can't find why I get error:

> syntax error: 'public' came as a complete surprise to me

on:

```
public root
    : NEWLINE* global_block EOF -> ^(Root global_block)
    ;
```

?

btw I also get:

```
syntax error: '->' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element 
syntax error: '^' came as a complete surprise to me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pragmatic solution

Just delete the `public` modifier. Rules are public by default.

### Reason `public` is not recognized

I don't know! According to the Antlr4 grammar (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4), `public` should be allowed. However, I am not sure whether this grammar is exactly the one used for Antlr4.

### A more severe problem in your spec

[AST constructors are no longer supported in Antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084533/how-to-generate-ast-in-antlr4) so `^(Root global_block)` is not possible anymore. You need a tree visitor (or listener) to build a custom tree:

Run `antlr` with the `-visitor` option to generate a visitor class. This class is a generic class which has a `visit` method for each rule, e.g.,

```
public class PropertyFileBaseVisitor<T> extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<T>
implements PropertyFileVisitor<T>
{
    @Override public T visitFile(PropertyFileParser.FileContext ctx) { ... }
    @Override public T visitProp(PropertyFileParser.PropContext ctx) { ... }
```

}

It returns any `T`, so you can simply write a visitor that builds a tree of your desired type and returns it. For a more in depth discussion of using visitors see [If/else statements in ANTLR using listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners)

Comment: I also get `syntax error: '->' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element` :S

Comment: I see ... May you provide tiny example of how can I resolve it with tree visitor

Comment: @Heather, a visitor-example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners