# ANTLR : '^' came as a complete surprise to me

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

I want to set root for AST in this grammar:

```
boolexp     : relexp op=(AND | OR)^ boolexp
        | relexp
        ;
```

but get this error:

```
'^' came as a complete surprise to me
```

What is the cause?

Comment: What exactly surprised you? What did you expect to see? What did you actually see?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, it's [the actual error message ANTLR returns](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/274120c2b6ea059ad8e9538103163667d2575a2c/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse/ToolANTLRParser.java#L69) :)

Comment: I just wanted to set op=(AND | OR) as ROOT.

Comment: @user3758844, you can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084533/how-to-generate-ast-in-antlr4

Answer (score 0):

If this is ANTLR 4, the AST operators have been removed in favor of automatic parse tree construction.

If this is ANTLR 3, you may need to move your labels inside the parentheses, like the following.

```
boolexp     : relexp (op=AND | op=OR)^ boolexp
        | relexp
        ;
```

Comment: So how should set root and create Visual AST?It is version 4;